# Correct representation of $\omega^2$ in Euler form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have been trying to write $\omega^2$ in Euler form, first $$\omega^2 = \frac{-1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2} ,$$ hence $|\omega^2| = 1$ and $\arg(\omega^2) = -\pi + \frac{\pi}{3}$ as $\omega ^2$ lies in the fourth quadrant which gives $\omega^2 = e^{\frac{-2i\pi}{3}}$.

But using [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), I derived that the cube roots for unity is $1$, $\exp \left(\frac{2i\pi}{3} \right)$ and $\exp \left( \frac{4i\pi}{3} \right)$. I am getting the value of $\omega = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}} $ but I am not sure how $e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}}=e^{\frac{-2i\pi}{3}}$? Please explain your answer.

Thanks,

Comment: Everything is right! Note that $e^{-2\pi i/3}=e^{4\pi i/3}$. (Divide the second by the first. You get $e^{2\pi i}$, which is $1$.)

Comment: @user6312:Yeps that's an easy fix but Julián Aguirre's answer is the right way to deduce it and works for other cases too :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any complex number $z\ne0$ there is an infinity of angles $\theta$ such that
$$
z=|z|(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=|z|e^{i\theta}.
$$
The difference between any two such angles is an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Thus, since
$$
\frac{4\pi}{3}=-\frac{2\pi}{3}+2\pi,
$$
you see that
$$
e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}}=e^{-\frac{2\pi}{3}}.
$$

Comment: Hm I got it thanks,but I think the general value of the argument is $Arg(z)= (2n\pi + \theta)$ where $arg(z) = \theta$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so $\large e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}}=e^{-\frac{2i\pi}{3}} = e^{\frac{10i\pi}{3}} ... $.

Comment: The _principal value of the argument_ of $z\ne0$ is usually defined as the only $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ such that $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$, and is represented as $\hbox{arg}(z)$. Sometimes $\hbox{Arg}(z)$ is defined as the _set_ of all arguments: $\hbox{Arg}(z)=\{\hbox{arg}(z)+2k\pi:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. In general, $z=|z|e^{(\hbox{arg}(z)+2k\pi)i}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes I meant the same thing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\large e^{\frac{4i\pi}{3}}=e^{\frac{-2i\pi}{3}}$

Comment: But could you hint me how?

Comment: Since $e^{2i\pi}=1$

Comment: Okay but I still don't get how is your hint going to lead me to that thing?

Comment: Aha got it :)